# Is it possible to get Google Analytics working in the browser with ionic?

Tags: javascript, android, google-analytics

I'm working with a team to build a mobile application with ionic. We also have the application hosted on a website, and we want to setup Google Analytics with it.

I know Google Analytics works on ionic for the mobile platform, but that same [method](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/using-google-analytics-ionicframework/) does not work in the browser.

Is it possible to have Google Analytics work in the browser when using the Ionic Framework? If it is possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible: using [ionic 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-analytics/)

```
declare let ga: any;

      if (this.platform.is('ios') || this.platform.is('android')) {
        // set startTrackerWithId
      } else {
        // web
         ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-XX', 'auto');
         ga('send', 'pageview');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , 
They offer a script for rapid integration .

Comment: While this technically answers the question (which after all asked for "if", not "how") the answer would profit from a source and maybe few details. As it stands I do not think this is terribly useful.